# PHP mysqli_query() hanging when connection lost

Tags: php, mysql

```
    $conn = get_conn();
    while(true)
    {
      $config_result = mysqli_query($conn, $config_row);
    }
```

My question is, if the connection was lost during the loop, it would take me 18 minutes(1080 seconds) to get the 'False' return of $config_result, so is mysqli_ping(). How can I fix this timeout to 3 seconds or less. My PHP version is 5.3.3 with Mysql 5.1.73 in Centos 6.8. Thanks.

Comment: Why this infinite loop `while(true)` ?

Comment: I will do other jobs in this loop, I just cut other code to make it clear: connect before loop -> lost connection during loop -> had to wait 1080 seconds to get the return of $config_result

Answer (score 0):

Try to use MySQL-Ping. With this code you can check if the connection is still here or not.

**Example**

```
//Check connection
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

//Check if server is alive
if(mysqli_ping($conn)) {
    printf("Our connection is ok!\n");
} else {
    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($conn));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I'm just wondering how to make the return timeout of $config_result shorter, it hangs over 18 minutes now. Thanks.

Comment: mysqli_ping is also hanging and need 1080 seconds to return, where should I fix this exactly 1080 seconds to 3 seconds?